# expected identifier or '(' before '}' token

Tags: c

I'm super new to C and keep getting this error for the last line. I've tried looking through my textbook and googling and looking through here. I think it's a small error but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
 /*Convert military time to standard time*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    double MilitaryTime, StandardTime;
    printf("Enter a military time (0000 to 2359): \n");
    scanf("%f", &MilitaryTime);


    {
        if(MilitaryTime <= 2359)
        {
            if(MilitaryTime <= 1159)
            StandardTime = MilitaryTime/100;
            printf("The regular time is: %2f AM\n", StandardTime);
            else
            StandardTime = (MilitaryTime - 1200)/100;
            printf("The regular time is: %2f PM\n", StandardTime);
        }
        else 
        printf("Error: Please enter a number between 0000 and 2359: %f\n");
        scanf("%f", &MilitaryTime);
    }
```

Comment: why java tag???

Comment: This error always indicates that you have unbalanced curly braces. Please put `{` and `}` around your code blocks, even the ones with a single operation. Remove blocks that you don't need, and format the code properly. The problem will fix itself. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take attention when opening and closing the `{ }`. They are responsible to define the scope of your variables and function. Take a look a little bit more about function scope. Have a nice code! :)

```
/*Convert military time to standard time*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  double MilitaryTime, StandardTime;
  printf("Enter a military time (0000 to 2359): \n");
  scanf("%f", &MilitaryTime);

  if(MilitaryTime <= 2359) {
      if(MilitaryTime <= 1159) {
        StandardTime = MilitaryTime/100;
        printf("The regular time is: %2f AM\n", StandardTime);
      } else {
        StandardTime = (MilitaryTime - 1200)/100;
        printf("The regular time is: %2f PM\n", StandardTime);
      }
  } else { 
    printf("Error: Please enter a number between 0000 and 2359: %f\n");
    scanf("%f", &MilitaryTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: ahahah :) I really prefer this kind of notation

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your main problem is lacking curly brackets {} after the **if**  and **else** statements.

Longer explanation:
In C, an if statement must be followed by curly brackets, or else only the first line after it is evaluated. If an else statement is used, it must follow up on the if immediately.

In other word what you are trying to do it:

```
if CONDITION
do:
    LINE1
    LINE2
    LINE3
    ETC...
else
do:
    ELSE_LINE1
    ELSE_LINE2
    ELSE_LINE3
    ETC...
```

but what you're telling your compiler is

```
if CONDITION
do:
    LINE1
Do anyway:
LINE2
LINE3
ETC...

else //This part is not defined and therefor the compiler doesn't understand 
     //you, as else must follow up right after an if
```

More so, you had two other problems:

One, you used the %f format to scan a variable of type double. %f is used to scan floats, not doubles. So if you want a to use a double precision variable you have to use `scanf("%lf", &MilitaryTime);`

Lastly, you opened a block of code right before your first if statement. While I don't see this causing problems with your current code, I don't see a reason to do that, and unless you have something specific in mind doing it, I would remove it.

And so, your fixed code would be :

```
/*Convert military time to standard time*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
double MilitaryTime, StandardTime;
printf("Enter a military time (0000 to 2359): \n");
scanf("%lf", &MilitaryTime);

if(MilitaryTime <= 2359)
    {
        if(MilitaryTime <= 1159)
        {
            StandardTime = MilitaryTime/100;
            printf("The regular time is: %2f AM\n", StandardTime);
        }

        else
        {
            StandardTime = (MilitaryTime - 1200)/100;
            printf("The regular time is: %2f PM\n", StandardTime);
        }

    }
        else
        {
            printf("Error: Please enter a number between 0000 and 2359: %f\n");
            scanf("%f", &MilitaryTime);
        }
}
```

One last note: Keep in mind that you are only checking that the input is smaller or equal to some number. You do not check that it is indeed a number, or that it is not negative, both of which would be good conduct to prevent your program from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because of:

```
if(MilitaryTime <= 1159)
    StandardTime = MilitaryTime/100;
    printf("The regular time is: %2f AM\n", StandardTime);
else
...
```

Note that indentions in C have no meaning (like for example in Python).

You code is is equivalent to:

```
if(MilitaryTime <= 1159)
{
    StandardTime = MilitaryTime/100;
}
    printf("The regular time is: %2f AM\n", StandardTime);
else
...
```

And as you can see, the `printf` comes after the `if` block, for the compiler
that is the end of the whole `if` block, then it sees an `else` without a
previous `if`, which is syntax error.

The correct code would be:

```
if(MilitaryTime <= 1159)
{
    StandardTime = MilitaryTime/100;
    printf("The regular time is: %2f AM\n", StandardTime);
} else {
    StandardTime = (MilitaryTime - 1200)/100;
    printf("The regular time is: %2f PM\n", StandardTime);
}
```

**edit**

Note that in C, the correct syntax for `if` and `while` block is

```
// very simplified version of the grammer

if(condition)
    statement-block;

while(condition)
    statement-block;

statement-block can be one of this:

 - ;

 - { statement1; statement2; ... }

 - statement
```

Generally speaking after an `if` and `while` you can have one statement only. If
you need more, then you have to wrap them in curly braces
`{ statement1; statement2; .. }`

There are cases where you only see a colon `;`:

```
// these are the same
if(condition);

if(condition)
{
}
```

Note that the identation of code doesn't matter to C. The semicolon `;` is what
tells the statements appart. This two programms are equivalent.

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, ");
    printf("world!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(void){printf("Hello, ");printf("world!\n");return 0;}
```